# Passing arrays between C and java with Swig

Tags: java, c, arrays, swig

I'm proficient in C but not in Java and I'm trying to use Swig to call C from Java. Simple calls work fine but I haven't been able to exchange arrays with either the `carrays.i` or the `arrays_java.i` methods. There aren't any complete examples of either.

AMItest.i:

```
%module AMItest
%{
#include "AMItest.h"
%}
%include "carrays.i"
%include "AMItest.h"
```

AMItest.h:

```
extern int AMItest(double *Array, int Start, int End);
```

AMItest.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "AMItest.h"
int AMItest(double *Array, int Start, int End) {
    if (End<=Start) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Start must be lower than End\n");
        return EDOM;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=End-Start; i++)
        Array[i]=sin(i/4.);
    return 0;
}
```

main.java:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.loadLibrary("AMItest_swig"); // File is libAMItest_swig.so
        double[] myArray = new double[11];
        System.out.println(AMItest.AMItest(myArray, 10, 20));
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ rm -f AMItest AMItest*.java SWIG*.java *.class *.o *.a *.so *_wrap.c
$ swig -java AMItest.i
$ gcc -fPIC -c AMItest.c AMItest_wrap.c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
$ gcc -shared AMItest.o  AMItest_wrap.o  -W  -o libAMItest_swig.so
$ javac main.java
main.java:7: error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_double
                System.out.println(AMItest.AMItest(myArray, 10, 20));
```

Googling for `SWIGTYPE_p_* errors` leads to surprisingly few (unhelpful) links. I've also tried using `arrays_java.i` or adding this to the .i file:

```
%array_functions( double, double )
%include <typemaps.i>
%apply (double *OUTPUT, int, int) {(double *Array, int Start, int End)};
```

Is this a problem with my .i file or with my Java ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt your AMItest.i like so:

```
%module AMItest
%{
#include "AMItest.h"
%}
%include "arrays_java.i"
%apply double[] {double *};
%include "AMItest.h"
```

> Sometimes a C function expects an array to be passed as a pointer...
>   One of the ways to wrap this is to apply the Java array typemaps that come in the arrays_java.i library file ... The ANY size will ensure the typemap is applied to arrays of all sizes. You could narrow the typemap matching rules by specifying a particular array size. Now you can use a pure Java array and pass it to the C code.

see documentation here: http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_unbounded_c_arrays

**Test**

Using your provided example with the modified AMItest.i as shown above, you will get the following output when calling `java main`:

```
0
0.0 0.24740395925452294 0.479425538604203 0.6816387600233342 0.8414709848078965 0.9489846193555862 0.9974949866040544 0.9839859468739369 0.9092974268256817 0.7780731968879213 0.5984721441039564
```

**More Efficient Alternative for Large Arrays**

In the case of an array of 11 double elements, you probably want to use the method shown above.  But I do not want to conceal the alternative method shown in the SWIG documentation:

> This approach is probably the most natural way to use arrays. However, it suffers from performance problems when using large arrays as a lot of copying of the elements occurs in transferring the array from the Java world to the C++ world. An alternative approach to using Java arrays for C arrays is to use an alternative SWIG library file carrays.i. This approach can be more efficient for large arrays as the array is accessed one element at a time.

Your example would require modification in two places like this:

AKITest.i:

```
%module AMItest
%{
#include "AMItest.h"
%}
%include "carrays.i"
%array_functions(double, doubleArray);
%include "AMItest.h"
```

Your slightly modified main.java would look like this then:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.loadLibrary("AMItest_swig"); // File is libAMItest_swig.so
        int size = 11;
        SWIGTYPE_p_double myArray = AMItest.new_doubleArray(size);
        AMItest.AMItest(myArray, 10, 20);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            System.out.print(AMItest.doubleArray_getitem(myArray, i) + " ");
    }
}
```

The result would be the same.

Comment: Awesome. But I must say, even reading the documentation, I don't really understand what `%apply double[] {double *}` or `%array_functions(double, doubleArray)` actually do.